# Wordpress Customizer Output Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Using Sage Roots theme I am having trouble outputting value from customizer setting. The setting/option displays on the admin then I fill in but it will not output.

**Customizer.php**

```
function customize_register($wp_customize) {

$wp_customize->add_setting(
'my_label',
array(
  'default' => '',
  'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'
)
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
  'my_label',
  array(
    'label' => 'My Label',
    'section' => 'title_tagline',
    'settings' => 'my_label',
    'transport' => 'postMessage'
  )
);

}
add_action('customize_register', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\customize_register');
```

**Customizer.js**

```
(function($) {
  wp.customize('my_label', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
      $('.my-label').text(to);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" title="My label"><button class="btn btn-primary pull-left my-label" alt="my label" ></button></a>
```

Comment: I found answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I found answer..

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" title="My label"><button class="btn btn-primary pull-left my-label" alt="my label" ><?php echo get_theme_mod(  'my_label', '' ); ?></button></a>
```